# Installing livescript and prelude-ls with npm and a gulpfile - is there no prelude-browser?

Tags: gulp, livescript

I have installed and used livescript and its `prelude-ls` library with bower successfully. I loaded `prelude-browser-min.js`:

```
// gulpfile
'static/bower_components/prelude-ls/browser/prelude-browser-min.js',
```

and I was able to import functions in my application code: `{map, filter, lines} = require 'prelude-ls'`.

Now I'm removing bower from my stack. I also install livescript and a `prelude-ls` package with npm but there is no `prelude-browser-min.js` file anymore (though [the doc](http://www.preludels.com/#installation) says to use that). As for javascript files there are a few under a `lib` directory: `index.js`, `Obj.js`, etc. I tried to load them all (`prelude-ls/**/*.js`) but there is a `module.exports` line somewhere in them and it fails to load my app ("module is not defined").

If there is no `prelude-browser-min.js`, how can I do ?

**update**: related issue: https://github.com/gkz/prelude-ls/issues/73

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allright, I'll keep bower for that then !